# Zookeeping: a puzzling job

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]
Your final answer should answer the question above.

Comment: ["a furry race of dog"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22a+furry+race+of+dog%22)?

Comment: Hm, I've figured out what's going on with three of these, but can't quite see how to continue just yet...

Comment: @Deusovi Same - rot13(naq gurve nafjref' yrggre frg vf cerggl fhfcvpvbhf va vgfrys...)

Answer (score 5):

The first thing of significance to note is that the three longer excerpts...

> ...have a very strange letter set - all contain J, X and Z among the letters. In fact, the more you look you can see that each of these contains **every letter of the alphabet except for a few**.
>
>  In fact, if we analyse which letters are missing we find that **these spell out the names of animals**! In the case of the top-left and top-right excerpts, these are actually *the animals talked about within their text* (the one at the bottom is harder to confirm as the same, due to its scattered nature).
>
>  Top-left - unused letters spell **DOVE**.
>  Top-right - unused letters spell **JACK** (as in *a male donkey*).
>  Bottom-centre - unused letters spell **SQUID**.

The question now is: what about the other excerpts?

> For some of them it seems it is possible to find animals that both suit their vague definitions and use none of the letters found in their text...
>
>  'bird of prey' = **HAWK**
>  'tailless, limbed amphibian that can leap' = **FROG**
>  'term Serpentes' = **BOA**
>  'a furry race of dog' = **SPITZ** (thanks @LukasRotter in comments)
>
>  Let's return to 'O...ed to specify the sex' shortly.

Next...

> Consider the letters of the animals we are finding here. These almost look like we might be trying to cover the alphabet again using the letters from their names - we've already covered A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W and Z (leaving LMNXY). If we can find an animal that satisfies the last remaining clue (whilst accounting for the as-yet-unused M), it is reasonable that we will find ourselves left with the letters to spell **LYNX**, which would then be the animal to answer the OP's question of "What's missing?" This would be especially appropriate, since a 'missing lynx' is a nice homophone for the puzzle-worthy 'missing links'!
>
>  The only thing missing from my answer at present is the animal behind '*O...ed to specify the sex*'. If my LYNX theory is correct then the animal's name must be made up only of letters from the set {ABGJKMQRUVWZ} (i.e. those letters that do not appear in the text or the word LYNX) and *must* include the letter M among them. However, the only animal name I can spot among these without reusing letters (since none of the others already found have repeated letters) is RAM - but I am unsure of how the context of 'specifying sex' is relevant for this animal... Perhaps some more thought still required to nail down that last missing animal.

Comment: Furry dog might be rot13(FCVGM), covering 3 of the remaining ones.

Comment: @LukasRotter Ooh! I think that might well be it! Nice spot, thanks :)

Comment: Your explanation to the last one looks reasonable, I think you've solved this :). IMO rot13(Gur B ybbxf zber yvxr n mreb, nyfb tvira gurer ner ab bgure hccrepnfr yrggref va gur grkg. Znlor 0/1 = ovanel = znyr/srznyr = z/s?)

Comment: @LukasRotter Aha, again I agree with you - hadn't spotted it wasn't an 'O' :)

Comment: Nearly there! However, the last clue does indeed start with a capital O...

Comment: @noneuclideanisms Ah, okay. I've removed that part of the write-up and left it a little more open-ended. There's only one name I'm seeing in the letters without repeats but can't spot any connection to the text. Perhaps someone else might be able to see it?

Comment: The last animal is indeed 'lynx', but the final answer is Charles Darwin, or maybe one of his works, as I suggested earlier. If you take letters from each of the animals' names and combine them, you can form "Charles Darwin". "Specify the sex" is a reference to "sexual selection". I'm still not sure about the exact rules, but I'm now more certain that I was on the right track with the answer I deleted.

Comment: After removing the letters that form "Charles Darwin" from the animals' names, you get {O, V, J, K, Q, U, A, K, F, O, G, B, O, S, P, T, Z, Y, X}, which suspiciously includes most of the letters in the acronyms of some of his works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoology_of_the_Voyage_of_H.M.S._Beagle Hope this helps.

Comment: @Vir The animal names cover the entire alphabet by design, so it's not surprising you could craft an arbitrary string out of them. (though the [currently known] names only have one R as opposed to Charles Darwin)

Comment: @LukasRotter "Charles Darwin" is not an arbitrary string and it's much less likely that you'd be able to use each of the animals' names in constructing it. And when you combine its likelihood with the last clue ("specify the sex", where 'specify is an obvious synonym of 'select'), the topic, some of the obvious features of this puzzle (the tag, the aged appearance of the snippets, and so on), I think it becomes pretty unlikely that this is a puzzle isn't in some way a reference. Again, I won't worry about finding the exact mechanism behind the puzzle, but I do think my hunch is a good one.

Comment: @Vir It's pretty much expected that all animal names would be used for a 13-letter string.  I meant that you could create almost anything you want with your method. Anyhow, I'll not drag this out any further in this comment section.

Comment: Guvf negvpyr unf gur rknpg grkg 'B... hfrq gb fcrpvsl rgp.' jvgu gur B nyzbfg rknpgyl nobir gur yvar yvxr va guvf chmmyr: uggcf://qhznf.ppfq.paef.se/qhznf-02047901/qbphzrag
Vg zragvbaf 'Enz' frireny gvzrf, ohg gur frpgvba va pbagrkg vf ernyyl ersreevat gb 'nal xvaq bs sbjy' naq va nqqvgvba vg zragvbaf bgure navznyf gung svg gur zvffvat yrggref, yvxr 'Oht' rgp. Fvapr 'Obn', 'Unjx', naq 'Fcvgm' frrz n ovg enaqbz (fheryl gurer ner bgure fanxrf/oveqf bs cerl/sheel qbtf gung pbhyq or pubfra), V jbaqre vs gurer vf zber vasbezngvba uvqqra be guvf jubyr guvat vf n erq ureevat.

Comment: I retract my comment. I just realized the obvious... Bug etc doesn't specify gender but r.. does. The 'x' in Oxford was intentionally cut. Seems like this is solved.

Comment: @Amoz That's interesting - that excerpt actually does match up, and the italicised 'O' comes from '**O**xford English Dictionary'. Since that section's talking about 'cocks and hens' though, I don't see a word that fits the necessary pattern yet... Hmmm...